# WPF. App crashes on win xp on change content of control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My app have the following code:

```
void ShuffleRadioAnswersText(List<RadioButton> rad)
    {
        List<TextBlock> texts = new List<TextBlock>();
        TextBlock content;
        foreach (var item in rad)
        {
            content = (TextBlock)item.Content;
            texts.Add(content);
        }

        Random rnd = new Random();
        foreach (var item in rad)
        {
            var txtToAdd = texts[rnd.Next(0, texts.Count)];
            item.Content = txtToAdd;
            TextBlock txt = item.Content as TextBlock;
            texts.Remove(txt);
        }
    }
```

When i try to launch it on windows xp(VMWare) it crashes on

```
item.Content = txtToAdd;
```

I've try some things but no result. I know I can shuffle TextBlock's text, but in some textblocks there are inlineCollections (text +  + text) and I can't set inlineCollection property of textblock cause it's readonly.
Does anybody has some ideas what to add?

EDIT:
Xaml part is:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,15,0,0" x:Name="StackAnswers">
        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource radioStyle}"  >
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource txtInRadioStyle}">
                SomeText
            </TextBlock>
        </RadioButton>`<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource radioStyle}"  >
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource txtInRadioStyle}">
                SomeText line 1 <LineBreak/> SomeText line 2
            </TextBlock>
        </RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

So there are no problems with content = (TextBlock)item.Content;
And I make it work on Windows xp this way:

```
List<TextBlock> texts = new List<TextBlock>();
            TextBlock content;
            foreach (var item in r)
            {
                content = (TextBlock)item.Content;
                texts.Add(content);
            }
            Random rnd = new Random();
            foreach (var item in r)
            {
                var txtToAdd = texts[rnd.Next(0, texts.Count)];
                string resStr = "";
                foreach (var it in txtToAdd.Inlines)
                {
                    var run = it as Run;
                    if (run != null)
                        resStr += run.Text;
                    var newline = it as LineBreak;
                    if (newline != null)
                        resStr += Environment.NewLine;
                }
                item.Content = resStr;
                texts.Remove(txtToAdd);
            }
```

PS: I got windows xp sp3.

Comment: could you please provide some info about errors that occur at the time of crash?

Comment: Invalidoperationexception at that row

Comment: Try- `txtToAdd.ToString()` if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you should check this.

In your code,
`item.Content = txtToAdd;`

This code is possible because [the TextBox applies the ContentPropertyAttribute attribute to the Text property.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-set-the-text-content-of-a-textbox-control)

The important thing is that [ContentPropertyAttribute Class
 only supports Windows XP SP3.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute(v=vs.100).aspx)

So, First, you should check your XP version.

> If the associated property of a **ContentPropertyAttribute** is not of type string or object, a type converter will be called at runtime. If a type converter cannot be found at runtime, an **exception is thrown**.

I hope this will help you.